# Creating heat/proximity map from vector line data

Tags: qgis, vector, heat-map

I wish to create a population pressure map using vector line data (roads), to assess forest degradation pressure using QGIS. I need a 'line density' raster output, that works in a similar way to the 'point density' heatmap function.

How do I generate a heatmap based on line proximity?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Our short [tour] emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  It is your second question that I think you should remove because it in its own right is to broad for focused Q&A.

Comment: there is the NNMLF plugin that estimates the spatial distribution pattern of linear features. could be a first step...

Comment: Thanks - will give it a look-see